# function app/logic app to send json files from storage account to Event Hub in Azure

Tags: azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps, azure-eventhub

I want to send files from a storage account container to Event Hub in Azure. what is the best solution to achieve this(function app/logic app). can this be achieved ?
Requirement is the json data in blob storage should be pushed to event hub.

*Please comment, if anyone has done this before.*

Comment: You need a distinct problem to solve, this question will be closed unless you do ... https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: And what would the flow be after the json is available in the Event Hub? How big are those files anyway?

Comment: @PeterBons a SIEM tool will pull the json content from event hub. the files are short, we are yet to get there, currently we are not send files from storage container to event hub

Comment: I'd say an event grid triggered function with an event hub output binding should do the trick.

Comment: sorry, I am new to azure, should I use a Blob triggered function with event hub output binding or event grid triggered function.

Answer (score 0):

1. We have created `logic app` as shown below:

[image]

2. Created an action to `get content` from azure blob storage container.

[image]

3. Created `Send event` action to send content from azure blob to event hub.
   [image]
4. Logic app ran successfully as shown below:

[image]